# Object throwing multiple instances even though it's configured for a single instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, multiple-instances, single-instance

I am coding in Python and I am facing a situation where my object is throwing out multiple instances even though it has been configured for a single instance. So I have multiple modules that is running a script and there is one module called mylogger.py which instantiates the logger object that stores and displays the logs of the script in a file and the console respectively. I am calling the module mylogger.py from multiple modules in my script. But I want to make sure that for those multiple calls from different modules I use the same initial object so that I do not get the same lines being inserted multiple times in my log file. But I am not sure even after proper configuration I am seeing multiple objects being created each time the function setLogger() is called from different modules.

```
# mylogger.py

import logging

logger = None


def setLogger(filename="logfile.txt"):
    global logger
    print("*********VALUE OF LOGGER IN FUNCTION******** ", logger)
    if logger is None:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)     # creating logger object only once
    if not getattr(logger, 'handler_set', None):
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.propagate = False
        logger.handler_set = True
    return logger
```

I am calling this file from multiple modules. I have included the parts which calls the mylogger.py file.

```
#firstModule.py
import mylogger
import os 
import sys

logger = mylogger.setLogger()
logger.info("Logger object in firstModule is ", logger)
# Some code 
# and print statements
# goes here
# Trigger next module by calling it using os.system(...)
os.system('python' + path_of_script/secondModule.py)
```

Now the secondModule.py calls the mylogger.py

```
#secondModule.py
import mylogger
import os 
import sys

logger = mylogger.setLogger()
logger.info("Logger object in secondModule is ", logger)

# Some code
#and print statements
#go here
#And then it calls some other module
```

So basically the logger object is different for firstModule.py and secondModule.py and for the next subsequent modules which prints out multiple lines of the same statement in the logfile.txt. However, the lines that get printed on the console through streamHandler() is fine as it only prints out single line for a single logger.info(). This seems very weird as both streamHandler() and fileHandler() were configured using the same function.

Comment: I answered your question below, but this may not actually help you, because I think you're asking the wrong question. In particular, this may be a so-called "XY problem". As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have two processes (through `os.system()`) so of course you have different objects. In order to "Trigger next module", use `import` instead.